# Coalescing QUIC short packet

Tags: udp, quic

I'm reading RFC9000 which is about QUIC protocol.
It says that Initial, 0-RTT, and Handshake packets can be coalesced in one UDP datagram, but Retry packets, Version Negotiation packets, and packets with a short header cannot be coalesced.

Why does QUIC mandate this rule?
Is there any issue when allowing coalescing of QUIC packets with short headers?

I think there is no problem when a short header has Length field and becomes to be coalesced in one UDP datagram.

Answer (score 0):

In situations where a Version Negotiation or a Retry packet is sent, there is usually no other packets or data that should be sent. It is therefore not necessary to technically allow the coalescing of such packets.

The same applies for short header packets. They carry one or multiple QUIC frames, which eliminates the need of coalescing QUIC packets.

Comment: This is correct; and to add to that: the reason that coalescing short headers packets is not needed, is because these are sent when the handshake is completed and no other (initial / handshake / 0-rtt) packets will be sent anymore. 
W.r.t. the "cannot": Retry and Short header packets have no length field, which is why they cannot be coalesced.